# How to pass array in C#

Tags: c#

I have a prototype:

```
  int[] medianFileter(int[] data);
```

and an array

```
  int[] intVal = new int[5];
```

How can I pass the intVal to the prototype in C#?

Comment: I don't understand how someone with 962 rep. and 2 silver badges ask such a simple question.

Comment: Because maybe his 964 (now) reputation points came from expertise in another programming language?  This isn't a C# specific site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um, you just call it (assuming you've got a real implementation to call):

```
int[] result = medianFileter(intVal);
```

Note that any changes made to the array within the method will show up in `intVal`: you're not passing each of the integers individually, but a reference to the whole array.

(There could be some trickiness here due to your use of the word "prototype" - it's not standard C# terminology, so I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If you could clarify the question, that would help.)

On a side note, method names in .NET are usually Pascal-cased, so this should probably be:

```
int[] result = ApplyMedianFilter(intVal);
```

Comment: +1 for 'not passing each of the integers individually, but a reference to the whole array'

Answer (score 0):

It's either I don't see some obvious weirdness here, or it's just usual function invocation:

```
int[] medianFiltered = medialFileter(intVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you would do,

```
medianFileter(intVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with:

```
medianFileter(intVal);
```

?